# Assignment to expression with array type, assigning values to an array

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors

i need to assign these values to the array but i keep receiving assignment to expression error, I'm wondering how I can assign values to those arrays. i try assigning the inputted value of arr into num but i believe I am missing something in that expression.

this codes job is to read the input of a temperature assign the input into a category of the type of day and give the average of the temperature

```
Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)> 100
Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)> 0
Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)> 50
Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)> -99

Hot days:   1
Pleasant days:  0
Cold days:  2

The average temperature was 50.00 degrees.
```

this is what an output should look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    //declare variables
    int num[30];
    int Cday[30];
    int Pday[30];
    int Hday[30];
    int total;
    int total_ave;
    double ave;
    int NHday=0;
    int NPday=0;
    int NCday=0;
    int arr;
    
    //ask input store into num, then decides if the number goes into which array
    
    do{
        printf("Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)>");
        scanf ("%d", &arr);
        num = arr;
    
        if(arr == -99)
        {
            break;
        }
    
        else if(arr<=60 && arr>=0){
            Cday = num;
        }
        else if(arr>=60 && arr<=84){
            Pday = num;
        }
        else if(arr<=84 && arr>=200){
            Hday = num;
        }
    
    }while(num >=0);
    
    //calculating the average
    total = sizeof(num);
    
    for(int i = 0;i< total; i++){
        total_ave = total_ave + num[i];
    }
    ave = total_ave / total;
    
    //to print the amount of times each day was in a category
    NHday = sizeof(Hday)/sizeof(Hday[0]);
    NPday = sizeof(Pday)/sizeof(Pday[0]);
    NCday = sizeof(Cday)/sizeof(Cday[0]);
    
    //printing the final statement once all the values are calculated
    printf("\nHot days:\t %d\n", NHday);
    printf("Pleasant days:\t %d\n", NPday);
    printf("Cold days:\t %d\n\n", NCday);
    
    printf("The average temperature was %.2f degrees.", ave);
    
    //stops compiling when -99 is entered not collected as information
    //
    //
    return(0);
}
```

i would also appreciate to know if how i am calculating how many items are in the array with the NHday CDay and Pday Calculations is the correct way to do it.

i am also wondering if my calculation for the average is correct. any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need arrays for the different types of days, just counter variables, which you increment based on the temperature range.

`total` should not be `sizeof(num)` for two reasons:

1. `sizeof` counts bytes, not array elements.
2. You only want the count of inputs, not the total size of the array. You can get the total by adding the counters of each type of day.

You don't have to put the temperatures in an array. Just add each day's temperature to the `total_ave` variable after the user enters it.

When you're calculating `ave`, you need to cast one of the variables to `double` so that floating point division will be used instead of integer division.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    //declare variables
    int num;
    int total;
    int total_ave = 0;
    double ave;
    int NHday=0;
    int NPday=0;
    int NCday=0;
    
    //ask input store into num, then decides if the number goes into which array
    
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)>");
        scanf ("%d", &num);
        if(num == -99)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(num<=60){
            NCday++;
        }
        else if(num<=84){
            NPday++;
        }
        else {
            NHday++;
        }
        total_ave += num;
    }
    
    //calculating the average
    total = NHday + NPday + NCday;
    ave = (double)total_ave / total;
    
    //printing the final statement once all the values are calculated
    printf("\nHot days:\t %d\n", NHday);
    printf("Pleasant days:\t %d\n", NPday);
    printf("Cold days:\t %d\n\n", NCday);
    
    printf("The average temperature was %.2f degrees.", ave);
    
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i didn't even realize the logic you used! but its a great way of solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning arr value to num array without using index. Your while loop should be like

```
while(i<30){
         printf("Enter a high temp reading (-99 to quit)>");
         scanf ("%d", &arr);
            if(arr==-99){
                break;
            }
            num[i] = arr;
            i++;
            total++;
             if(arr<=60 && arr>=0){
                     NCday++;
                   }
             else if(arr>=60 && arr<=84){
                     NPday++;
                     }
             else if(arr>=84 && arr<=200){
                     NHday++;
                 }
        }
```

Now

```
total = sizeof(num);
```

This will give you the total size of num array which is 30*4=120 as int data type has 4 byte size.
If you are not filling all 30 values then you need to know the number of values your are going to use from that array. That's why I am incrementing total as I am inserting values in num array which will help later.

```
for(int i = 0;i< total; i++){
     total_ave = total_ave + num[i];
 }
 ave = total_ave / total;
```

If you just want to know the count of cold, hot days then you can increment them in while loop and print those.

```
printf("\nHot days:\t %d\n", NHday);
printf("Pleasant days:\t %d\n", NPday);
printf("Cold days:\t %d\n\n", NCday);
```

And first initialize the variables.

```
int num[30];
int total=0;
int total_ave=0;
double ave;
int NHday=0;
int NPday=0;
int NCday=0;
int arr=0;
int i=0;
```